# Difference between "super" and "super do |u|" using context of Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, super

Ok so I think I get what super `does` standalone. Basically in Devise, if `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`, then on any action, having a `super` will first call the logic for that same named action in the parent `Devise::RegistrationsController`, before then calling what you've written.

In other words...

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    puts "this is in the parent controller"
  end
end

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
    puts "this is in the child controller"
  end
end

# Output if users#new is run would be:
# => "this is in the parent controller"
# => "this is in the child controller"

# If super were reversed, and the code looked like this
# class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  #  def new
    #  puts "this is in the child controller"
    #  super
  #  end
#  end
# Then output if users#new is run would be:
# => "this is in the child controller"
# => "this is in the parent controller"
```

What I'm curious about is that I've seen some people do this:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super do |user|
      puts "something"
    end
  end
end
```

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what the `do block` is accomplishing. In my case, after the resource (the user) is created, I want to call an additional method on that resource (the user).

Current code:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super do |user|
      user.charge_and_save_customer
      puts user.inspect
    end
  end
end
```

I'm just wondering if this would be any different than doing:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
    resource.charge_and_save_customer
    puts resource.inspect
  end
end
```

In case it's helpful, I've included the parent `Devise::RegistrationsController` code below:

```
def new
  build_resource({})
  set_minimum_password_length
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with self.resource
end
```

Comment: well their `new` method takes a block (hence the `yield`)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let me try to explain what is going on here:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super do |user|
      user.charge_and_save_customer
      puts user.inspect
    end
  end
end
```

When you call `super`, you are going back to the parent `new` action, so the following code will be executing now:

```
def new
  build_resource({})
  set_minimum_password_length
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with self.resource
end
```

But wait... here is an `yield`, so it yields the current `resource` to the block, you can think of the block like a method, it needs a parameter (`user`), and here `resource` (from parent) will be the parameter:

```
# Here resource is assigned to user
user.charge_and_save_customer
puts user.inspect
```

Now, since the block is executed completely, it will start executing the super again:

```
respond_with self.resource
```

Comment: I see, so in this case, since there's a `super` and a `yield` to the block, then basically the code in the `super do` gets executed wherever the `yield` is called. In this case, it allows me to inject code in the middle of the parent action. If there were NOT a `yield` statement, then `super do` would be useless, and `super` by itself would run the entirety of the parent action (meaning I could inject code either at the beginning or end). Is that correct?